# pythonanywhere with mlab(mongoDB)

Tags: mongodb, pythonanywhere, mlab

when I try to connect to my application deploy at Pythonanywhere database does not working, its seems that he can't reach to him.
when I am using my computer and run the app all seems to be perfect.
any one any ideas?

Thanks very much.

Comment: I have a paid plan as they require.

Comment: There's no way to work out what the problem is or how to fix it based on the information you've provided.

Answer (score 1):

Hey after checking out I found that pythonanywhere required paid plan in order to use mlab services, or others services.